Exception is thrown in Controller Advice
An exception occurs which is handled by an @ExceptionHandler.
The spring exception resolver then determines that the media type does not match and cannot generate the response error which is the @ExceptionHandler returning.
An HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException is thrown, which is not processed.
I tried to create another exception handler for HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException. However, this is not called.
In ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver I saw this lines
catch (Throwable invocationEx) {
    if (disconnectedClientHelper.checkAndLogClientDisconnectedException(invocationEx)) {
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
    // Any other than the original exception (or a cause) is unintended here,
    // probably an accident (e.g. failed assertion or the like).
    if (!exceptions.contains(invocationEx) && logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        logger.warn("Failure in @ExceptionHandler " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
    }
    // Continue with default processing of the original exception...
    return null;
}

So it looks like its intendent that the exception is propagated to a new exception handler.
If it is not handled by a spring @ExceptionHandler, how do you solve the problem?
